# Not able to login with my hosted login page

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying host my code in a hosting site www.my3gb.com
My code is working fine with my pc but not when i hosted there....Look at this code...

```
<html>
<body bgcolor="green">

<?php
$conn=mysql_connect("http://www.my3gb.com/phpmyadmin/","username","password");
mysql_select_db("mohit007kumar00_cboy",$conn);
print "<h1>connected</h1>";
$rs=mysql_query("select * from signup where user='".$_POST['t1']."'");
print "<h1>queried</h1>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
    print "<h1>under while</h1>";
    if($row['pswd']==$_POST['t2'])
    {
        print "<h1>You are alowed</h1>";
    }
    else
    {
        print "<h1>not alowed</h1>";
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

and the login page is .....

```
    <html>
    <body bgcolor="yellow">
    <center>
    <h1>Login Application</h1>
    <form action="log.php" method="post">
    user<input type="text" name="t1"><br><br>
    pswd<input type="password" name="t2"><br><br>
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
    </center>
    </body>
 </html>
```

on my pc it will show the output like this....
connected
queried
under while
You are alowed
while on my hosted link it will show the output like this......
connected
queried
  you can view my login page here http://mohit007kumar00.my3gb.com/test.php

Comment: Due to the fact that you're not getting into the loop... are there any entries in your DB on the server?

Comment: Ya There is a table...I am using that table for login.

Comment: Insert a var_dump($rs); directly after the mysql_query line

Comment: ok, so the query is never executed correctly... add a or die(mysql_error()) directly behind the mysql_query: mysql_query() or die(mysql_error()); this will show you the problem

Comment: It will show    Can't connect to MySQL server on 'http' (4)    so what i have to do....I submited all the information correctly...!!

Comment: @user528050 i've already answered your question (*I think MySQL won't connect to a hosted phpMyAdmin*) and so it says almost the same.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is here:

```
mysql_connect("http://www.my3gb.com/phpmyadmin/","username","password");
```

try

```
mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
```

I think MySQL won't connect to a hosted phpMyAdmin but maybe it's my misunderstanding.

Comment: @user528050 Maybe just because echoing out these words isn't bound to a condition so it will always showing them.

Comment: yeh it's not working....you can check out this..http://mohit007kumar00.my3gb.com/test.php

Comment: @user528050 How could i check out when i have no account on this server?

Answer (score 0):

You are running the query when the page loads for the first time also, You have to run it only  when the user clicks on the submit button.

Before running the query, check whether the user clicked the submit button,

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit_button_name'])){//set name and value for submit button
    //your code here
}
?>
```